# Create new calendar object on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I've assignment where I'm to create a slider with calendar months.

The slider should on click create a new object (with next month), and delete a previous one.

By default 4 months should be created but only 2 should be visible (hence the slider).

So what I should achieve is the array with 4 generated months, and on click the first one is deleted and next month is generated.

[January, February, March, April] -> on click next slide -> [February, March, April, May]

[January, February, March, April] -> on click prev slide -> [December ,January, February, March]

So far I've written a script which generates 2 calendars with two months (e.g. January and February).

[image]

I'm using jQuery ui-calendar and slick slider as plugins.

The code I've written so far is:

HTML

```
<div class="twoCalendars">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="calendar-wrapper">
                            <div class="doubleCalendar"></div>
                            <button id="prev">Previous Month</button>&nbsp;
                            <button id="next">Next month</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="calendar-wrapper">
                            <div class="doubleCalendar2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and Javascript

```
function twoCalendars(day, month, year) {

var calendarTable = [];

var calendar = jQuery('.doubleCalendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

var calendar2 = jQuery('.doubleCalendar2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month + 1,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

jQuery('#next').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
});

jQuery('#prev').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ui-datepicker-prev').trigger("click");
});

}

twoCalendars(7, 3, 2017);
```

I know It's a lot to ask, but unfortunanetly I'm really stuck and my job depends on it.

hope you guys can help me.

I will answer all the additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do everything that you asked for the past hour or so, I must say it is possible but it would take me more time.

Here's an incomplete solution using Jquery ui slider 
the JQuery datepicker to previous.
[slider](https://codepen.io/rimaghawa/pen/LyWjOW)
        function twoCalendars(day, month, year) {

```
var calendarTable = [];

var calendar = jQuery('.doubleCalendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

var calendar2 = jQuery('.doubleCalendar2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month + 1,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

jQuery('#next').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
});

jQuery('#prev').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ui-datepicker-prev').trigger("click");
});

}

twoCalendars(7, 3, 2017);

 $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({  
      slide: function( event, ui ) {  

        updateHandleValues(ui);
      },
 change: function(event, ui) {
    updateHandleValues(ui);
  }
    });

  } );

function updateHandleValues(ui) {
    //$('#calendar-wrapper"').removeClass("doubleCalendar2", "fast")
 //$('#calendar-wrapper"').addClass("doubleCalendar2", "slow")
        jQuery('.ui-datepicker-prev').trigger("click");

}
```

Maybe you can do a function that determines the position of slider and based on that you go forward or backwards in the date picker.

I know it is not much, I hope someone else will give you a complete solution.